# Azure DevOps 2019 view build process inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have upgraded our build server into Azure DevOps 2019 and since we are more used to viewing our build process within Visual Studio I wanted to check if this is possible.

When the user right clicks the build definition in Visual Studio that the  build process web view would appear as a tab inside Visual Studio instead of opening in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

From VS 2015 you can't open the new build system (vNext) in the VS, but only to open it in the browser.

The old XAML build still can be viewed in the VS (but is not recommended to use them...).

Comment: I am a bit surprised this is not possible since this is just a website and I assume Visual Studio could open a website in a tab. Maybe 3rd party extensions?

Comment: @doorman It is not supported, but it is a good feature, you may submit it here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/tfs.html?type=idea

Comment: I added it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/639927/azure-devops-2019-view-build-process-inside-visual.html